# JPA JOIN for simple access

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I would like to be able to include an @Entity from another table using a foreign key.  I'm following guides but I'm still confused and can't seem to get this working.  The end goal would be something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Labor", schema = "dbo", catalog = "database")
public class LaborEntity {
    private int laborId;
    private Timestamp laborDate;
    private Integer jobNumber;
    private Integer customerId;

    //mapping of customer to labor
    private CustomerEntity customer;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "LaborID", nullable = false)
    public int getLaborId() {
        return laborId;
    }

    public void setLaborId(int laborId) {
        this.laborId = laborId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "LaborDate", nullable = true)
    public Timestamp getLaborDate() {
        return laborDate;
    }

    public void setLaborDate(Timestamp laborDate) {
        this.laborDate = laborDate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "JobNumber", nullable = true)
    public Integer getJobNumber() {
        return jobNumber;
    }

    public void setJobNumber(Integer jobNumber) {
        this.jobNumber = jobNumber;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CustomerID", nullable = true)
    public Integer getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = CustomerEntity.class)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CustomerID",                //in this table
            referencedColumnName = "CustomerID",    //from CustomerEntity
            insertable = false, updatable = false,
            foreignKey = @javax.persistence.ForeignKey(value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
    public CustomerEntity getCustomer() {
        return this.customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(CustomerEntity customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
```

Anyway, the end goal is to get the Customer data from the Customer table as part of the Labor entity so it can be accessed directly with something like `getCustomerEntity()`.  I supposed I would have to accomplish it by querying first using a JOIN like so:

```
TypedQuery<LaborEntity> query = entityManager.createQuery(
        "SELECT l FROM LaborEntity l " +
                "INNER JOIN CustomerEntity c " +
                "ON l.customerId = c.customerId " +
                "WHERE l.laborDate = '" + date + "'", LaborEntity.class);
List<LaborEntity> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

And then I can simply access the Customer that's associated like so:

```
resultList.get(0).getCustomer().getCustomerName();
```

Am I dreaming or is this actually possible?

Comment: Why do you mix up annotations on fields and methods levels?

Comment: First of all, since you declared `@Id` on top of the getter, all JPA annotations must go on top of getters. Alternatively, you can move the `@Id` mapping, as well as the mappings for all the other properties, to the field level. But don't mix the two

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is completely possible.
(I'm not sure about what was the question though - but assuming you only want get it working)

1. You query needs to be a JPQL, not an SQL. And the Join is different on JPQL:

   ```
    "SELECT l FROM LaborEntity l " +
       "JOIN l.customer c " +
       "WHERE ... "
   ```

The join starts from the root entity and then you use the field name (not column).
You can also use `JOIN FETCH`, then the associated entity (customer) will be loaded in the same query. (that is, Fetch EAGER)

Other recommendations:

- Don't concat the parameters like that `date`. Instead use `setParameter`.
- You don't need those `@Basic`
- You don't need that `targetEntity = CustomerEntity.class`. It'll be detected automatically.